# EntityFramework 6.2.0 Code-First Migrate.exe throwing "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)"

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

When migrating the database by running "Update-Database" inside the VS2017's Package Manager Console, everything is OK.

But running it using the "Migrate.exe" throws "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)".
The command is as follows:

**Migrate.exe "D:\TestEFMigration\TestEFMigration.dll" /startUpDirectory=D:\TestEFMigration\ /startupConfigurationFile="D:\TestEFMigration\TestEFMigration.dll.config" -verbose -force**

Please help.